# toString method seems to be only working once even tho it is called multiple

Tags: java, linked-list, tostring

I am trying to figure out why my toString() function will only work a singular time while adding another pizza. This is the output from the first created pizza which is as expected and functioning well

```
$ kitchen = new Kitchen()                                              
$ pizza = new Pizza()                                                   
$ pizza.toString()                                                      

-> "no crust pizza with no toppings and no sauce: $0.00"              
$ pizza.ingredients.add(kitchen.ingredients.get(1))                     
-> true                                                                 
$ pizza.toString()                                                     

-> "Thick crust pizza with no toppings and no sauce: $3.50"             
$ pizza.ingredients.add(kitchen.ingredients.get(2))                     
-> true                                                                
$ pizza.toString()                                                 

-> "Thick crust pizza with no toppings and Tomato sauce: $4.50"         
$ pizza.ingredients.add(kitchen.ingredients.get(5))                   
-> true                                                            
$ pizza.toString()                                                     

-> "Thick crust pizza with Olives and Tomato sauce: $6.00"           
$ pizza.ingredients.add(kitchen.ingredients.get(7))                    
-> true                                                              
$ pizza.toString()                                                     

-> "Thick crust pizza with Olives, Beef and Tomato sauce: $8.75"      
$ pizza.ingredients.add(kitchen.ingredients.get(4))                     
-> true                                                                
$ pizza.toString()                                                      

-> "Thick crust pizza with Olives, Beef, Capsicum and Tomato sauce:
```

but the output of another pizza is as follows

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT                                                         Current output

Creating new pizza                                                      Creating new pizza
Ingredient(s): Thin                                                     Ingredient(s): Thin
Thin crust pizza with no toppings and no sauce: $3.00                <
Ingredient(s): Tomato                                                   Ingredient(s): Tomato
Thin crust pizza with no toppings and Tomato sauce: $4.00            <
Ingredient(s): Jalapenos                                                Ingredient(s): Jalapenos
Thin crust pizza with Jalapenos and Tomato sauce: $5.00              <
Ingredient(s): Beef                                                     Ingredient(s): Beef
Thin crust pizza with Jalapenos, Beef and Tomato sauce: $7.75        <
```

=========================================================================edit

After analyzing my code it appears that the linkedlist ingredients in the class Pizza is not being modified so the issue would be with my testing method which is below.

```
public void testing(Ingredient ingredient1){  
    for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients){
        if (ingredient1.ingtoString().equals(ingredient)){
            ingredients.add(ingredient1);
        }
    }
}
```

and that method is called by my Kitchen class, like so.

```
  public void nameMatch(String match){
        Pizza pizza = new Pizza();
        for (Ingredient ingredient : ingredients){
            if (match.equals(ingredient.ingtoString())){
                pizza.testing(ingredient);
            }
        }
        pizza.toString();
    }
```

and finally, this is what is being used to create the pizza and call these methods

```
public void create() {
    System.out.println("Creating new pizza");
    String ingredient1 = "";
    while (!ingredient1.equals(".")){
        System.out.print("Ingredient(s): ");
        ingredient1 = (In.nextLine());
        kitchen.nameMatch(ingredient1);
    }
    System.out.println("ORDER SUMMARY");
    kitchen.nameMatch(ingredient1);
}
```

quick note all these methods are in 3 separate classes

Comment: Please read [mcve] and then add the missing parts to your question. Like... The code?!

Comment: my bad sorry, edited to what should be causing the issues :)

Comment: Showing us a couple of tiny snippets of code doesn't help us reproduce your problem.  You'll need to show your whole program, if you want help finding what's wrong with it.

Comment: does the current edit help out with that issue?

Comment: You're making it extremely difficult to help you.  Why can't you show us your whole program?  Do you not want help?

Comment: My whole program is fairly long with a bunch of methods that aren't currently being used but if you require I will supply it

Comment: Well, somebody has now managed to give you an answer, so if that answer works for you, then you needn't bother.  Otherwise, a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example would be a really good thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `nameMatch` you create a *new* pizza, add the ingredient to *that* pizza and then throw the pizza away. I assume you want to create a single pizza and all of the ingredients to it.

Plus, `nameMatch` doesn't actually print anything. `pizza.toString()` will convert the pizza to a string, but if you want to *print* that string you need to call `System.out.println` - e.g. `System.out.println(pizza.toString());`

Comment: Your assumption is correct, How would I go about creating a single pizza until it is complete?

Comment: @Dan by running `new Pizza()` once and then calling `testing` a bunch of times on that Pizza object.

Comment: after trying that I keep getting "no crust pizza with no toppings and no sauce: $0.00" after every ingredient